# Regular expression: match single characters AND/OR groups of characters (strings) at the same time?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'd like to be able to match zero or more of a list of characters AND/OR match zero or more of a list of strings.

**Example:** `Here is my 12345 test string 123456.`

**Target:** `Here is my 45 test string .`

So I wish to remove `1`, `2`, and `3`, but only remove `456` if it's a whole string.

I have tried something like `/[123]+456+/gs` but I know this is wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "zero or more of a list of characters" will match everywhere! (`@matches = "12345" =~ /a*/g; print scalar @matches, " matches found\n"`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/[123]|456/` may be what you want.

Comment: Excellent - I just used `/[123]|456/gs` - thank you very much!

**Edit:** I see you made an edit to remove your first example - you should keep this in as it could be useful to those looking to find strings at word boundaries: `/[123]|\b456\b/gs`

Comment: @dancingpriest if this worked, please mark it as your answer (click the tick)

Comment: @dancingpriest below the up/down triangles there is a small white tick. This indicates that you have accepted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
$str = "Here is my 12345 test string 123456.";
$res = preg_replace('/[123]|456/','',$str);
echo $res;
```

Output:

```
Here is my 45 test string .
```

Answer (score 0):

For javascript, this works:

```
var oldString = 'Here is my 12345 test string 123456.';

var newString = oldString.replace(/[123](456)?/g, '');
```

Comment: No, bad. This will only remove the string `456` when it is preceeded by a `1`, `2` or `3` character (which is also removed).

Comment: I thought the requirements were pretty loosely defined... but if you want to remove 456 even when not preceded by 1,2 or 3, just add a ? after the [123] (that is, oldString.replace(/[123]?(456)?/g, ''))